# Php function doesn't see mysqli connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I can't use mysqli queries within php function without violating the DRY principle.
Before my function I have following mysql configuration code:

```
//database configuration
$config['mysql_host'] = "myhost.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com";
$config['mysql_user'] = "mylogin";
$config['mysql_pass'] = "mypassword";
$config['db_name']    = "mydbname";
$config['table_name'] = "mytablename";
$connection = mysqli_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass'], $config['db_name']);
```

And my function looks like this:

```
function writeLog($isError) {
    global $connection, $ipLong, $datetime, $procedure_index, $gotResults;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO  user_log VALUES (NULL, ";
    $sql .= "\"$ipLong\", \"$datetime\", \"$procedure_index\", \"$gotResults\", \"$isError\"";
    $sql .= ");";
    mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}
```

I also tried to send connection as input variable like this:

```
function writeLog($isError, $connection) {
    global $ipLong, $datetime, $procedure_index, $gotResults;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO  user_log VALUES (NULL, ";
    $sql .= "\"$ipLong\", \"$datetime\", \"$procedure_index\", \"$gotResults\", \"$isError\"";
    $sql .= ");";
    mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}
```

Neither are working. The only working possibility I found is when I copy-paste my database configurations in my function, but it's not an option, because i need to execute queries in multiple functions. How can I fix it?

P.S. Bad, but working code:

```
//database configuration
$config['mysql_host'] = "myhost.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com";
$config['mysql_user'] = "mylogin";
$config['mysql_pass'] = "mypassword";
$config['db_name']    = "mydbname";
$config['table_name'] = "mytablename";
$connection = mysqli_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass'], $config['db_name']);

function writeLog($isError) {
    //database configuration, again. totally violating DRY principle.
    $config['mysql_host'] = "myhost.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com";
    $config['mysql_user'] = "mylogin";
    $config['mysql_pass'] = "mypassword";
    $config['db_name']    = "mydbname";
    $config['table_name'] = "mytablename";
    $connection = mysqli_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass'], $config['db_name']);

    global $ipLong, $datetime, $procedure_index, $gotResults;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO  user_log VALUES (NULL, ";
    $sql .= "\"$ipLong\", \"$datetime\", \"$procedure_index\", \"$gotResults\", \"$isError\"";
    $sql .= ");";
    mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Tip: Start small. Build up. Keep things more modular, for example, by not hard-coding some big query in your function. Test frequently and pay attention to when something breaks. Use version control to identify defects.

Comment: Define "doesn't see". Is your code color blind or wearing sunglasses?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `global` keyword and changing the scope of your connection variable and including the database connection variable as a function parameter are both valid methods to accomplish this task.

But since both of those aren't working, it's possible that you may have closed a previously opened connection before the function call.

```
mysqli_close($connection); <== Closed connection.

function writeLog($isError) <== Results in Error
function writeLog($isError, $connection) <== Results in Error
```